# How to get session variable/data outside of laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies

Is there any way to get session variable/data outside of the laravel application?

I have a project in core php (e.g: myproject) directory and now I want to signup/signin from laravel which will be placed in internal directory (e.g: myproject/laravel). I want to get signed-in user's details through session in myproject directory.

Is there any way/alternate for that?

Comment: some people will oversimplify it by storing user info in cookie to "commmunicate" between application instances (additional security measure will be needed). the other one would be implementing proper SSO such as SAML or JWT.

Comment: is there any alternate way instead of session-cookies ?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add `session_start();` in public/index.php on the top.
After that still need to set your external sessions in the classic way `$_['mysession'] = 'something';`. Remember that this will not work if you want to access auth() methods outside Laravel.